# Prime factors of numbers of form $a^2+2b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We are just being introduced to proofs in our class, and my teacher has offered a bounty. If anyone can prove the following statement, at any point during the year, we will get no homework for that week.

> Call a prime number $2$-expressible if it can be expressed in the form
>   $a^2+2b^2$ and $2$-inexpressible if it cannot. If two numbers $x$ and
>   $y$ have no common factor, $x^2+2y^2$ either has no $2$-inexpressible
>   prime factors or more than 1.

I've managed to prove this through a sort of convoluted and hard to follow argument using modular congruence, but I'm convinced there is a simple proof that I am missing. Is there any proof of this that uses only elementary number theory?

Comment: Is it a bit cheeky if the proof used to get no homework comes from maths stack exchange? :) This is not a criticism by the way, just a comment!

Comment: @snulty I figured it was okay since I already found and submitted a proof that I came up with on my own, and I just wanted to know if there were better options :D

Comment: I read the part about you already having a proof :) I was just curious. It's an interesting problem!

Comment: Can you unaccept my answer please ? I made a mistake and your approval prevents me from deleting it. I apologize

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

$\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ is an Unique Factorization Domain. In fact, it is an Euclidean Domain.

Comment: I guess that the downvoter thinks that this is not *elementary* number theory. But the fact that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ is an Euclidean Domain can be proved with simple arguments. If OP does not consider this "elementary", I'll delete the answer, though.

Comment: Thank you, I had not thought of this! Sadly, I believe my teacher won't accept a proof using UFD's, for an introductory course in number theory. But +1 in any case!

Comment: @TreFox Well, since you have upvoted it, the answer will remain undeleted. I'm glad you liked it.

Comment: I also upvoted it, when I saw the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

I think I fixed the proof, and it is rather elementary, but not so simple...

We're working with $N>1$  ($N=1=1^2+2\times0^2$ has no inexpressible prime factor)

Notice that according to [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity), $(a^2+2b^2)(c^2+2d^2)=(ac+2bd)^2+2(ad-bc)^2$.

Therefore, the set of all numbers of the form $x^2+2y^2$ is closed under multiplication.

Let's suppose $N=x^2+2y^2$ has exactly one $2$-inexpressible prime factor.

Then $N$ can be expressed as  $N=x^2+2y^2=(X^2+2Y^2)I$ where $I$ is the only inexpressible prime factor. $I$ is necessarily odd since $2=0^2+2\times1^2$ is $2$-expressible. If $2|N$, then $2|x^2$, and so $2|x$ since $2$ is a prime, so $x$ would be even. Assuming this is the case, dividing by $2$ yields $\frac N2=N'=\frac 12 (4x'^2+2y^2)=2x'^2+y^2=(2X'^2+Y^2)I$. It is then possible to iterate the same reasoning until $N$ becomes odd (since you mentioned that $x$ and $y$ have no common factors, then once at most is sufficient). If $N$ is odd and $I$ is odd then $2X'^2+Y^2$ has to be odd too.

Since squares are congruent to $0,1$ or $4 \pmod 8$ and $N$ is odd,  $N=x^2+2y^2\equiv1$ or $3 \pmod 8$, and $2X'^2+Y^2\equiv1$ or $3\pmod 8$ too, so $I\equiv 1,3$ or $\frac 13 \pmod 8\equiv1$ or $3\pmod 8$.

So $I$ is an odd prime such that $I\equiv 1$ or $3\pmod 8$.  However, [it can be shown](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/Math313/HW2Sol.pdf) (relatively elementarily, although the proof is long and tedious...) that such primes are always $2$-expressible. This is a contradiction.

Therefore, either $N$ has no $2$-inexpressible factors, or it has more than $1$.

Comment: "$N$ is obviously not a prime, so if $p|N$, then $p=2$." Why?

Comment: @Yuxiao You are right, I made a mistake there (and can't delete it)

Comment: I think it's correct. Just one thing, you may avoid iteration (which seems not so neat) like this. Let $N$ be the least number that satisfies the conditions in the question. Now if $2|N$ then $N/2$ is also a number that satisfies the conditions, but $N/2<N$, a contradiction.